# C# Dictionary<string,object> Удалить объекты с пустым значением

Tags: c#, linq, словари

есть метод, который принимает на вход Dictionary<string,object>, object - это вложенный Dictionary<string,string>. Его задача - Если object - Dictionary<string,string> и его значение null, то удалить пару из этого вложенного словаря. Если object - это string, проделать то же самое, но с простым словарем(а не составным). На выходе получаем измененный Dictionary<string,object>. А теперь, собственно, вопрос. Каким образом можно упростить код, заюзав, например LINQ? Мой код:

```
private object DelNullElements(Dictionary<string,object> Dict)
    {
        foreach (var item in Dict)
        {
            if (item.Value is Dictionary<string,string>)
            {
                foreach(var D in (item.Value as Dictionary<string, string>))
                {
                    if (D.Value == null)
                    {
                        (item.Value as Dictionary<string, string>).Remove(D.Key);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (item.Value == null)
                {
                    Dict.Remove(item.Key);
                }
            }
        }
        return Dict;
    }
```

Comment: вы приводите словать в object и храните его как значение в другом словаре. Если хотите упростить код, начните с ваших структур данных.

Comment: В словаре может быть что угодно, хоть другой словарь. Мои структуры данных менять не надо, вопрос вообще в другом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделаю обзор кода.

Возвращаемый тип `object` - почему? Ведь из метода возвращается словарь. И возвращается тот же самый, который поступил на вход.
Я бы изменил сигнатуру метода, сделав тип возврата `void`. Теперь сразу понятно, что внутри метода не создаётся новый словарь, а изменяется параметр.

Название `DelNullElements` - не стоит экономить несколько букв. Следует писать слово полностью: `Delete`. Более того, лично я бы использовать `Remove` - по аналогии с методом словаря - это будет более последовательно. Далее, мы удаляем *значения* - values из словаря. В итоге я бы назвал метод `RemoveNullValues`.

В соответствии с [правилами именования](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-parameters), параметр должен быть в camelCasing, то есть `dict`.

Аналогично переменная `D` не должна быть заглавной. И лучше дать ей имя не состоящее из одной буквы. Название `item` уже занято (хорошее название!), поэтому можно назвать её, например, `pair` - от типа `KeyValuePair`.

Далее, используем [Type pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern) ключевого слова `is`. Это сделает код более лаконичным и уберёт лишние приведения типа (что, кстати, медленно).

Итог:

```
private void RemoveNullValues(Dictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        if (item.Value is Dictionary<string, string> innerDict)
        {
            foreach (var pair in innerDict)
            {
                if (pair.Value == null)
                {
                    innerDict.Remove(pair.Key);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (item.Value == null)
            {
                dict.Remove(item.Key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Теперь о LINQ. Да, переписать код можно. Но я бы не стал. Если использовать метод `ToDictionary`, то это будет создавать новый словарь. А этот класс - очень тяжеловесная структура данных. И потреблять лишнюю память без причины я не вижу смысла.

А если использовать LINQ просто для прохода по словарю, это практически не сократит код, но опять-таки замедлит его. Вернее, сократит лишь визуально, за счёт устранения фигурных скобок (которые можно убрать и в текущем коде).

---

Еще можно опционально заменить внутренние `if` на `switch`, что опять же суть кода не поменяет.

```
private void RemoveNullValues(Dictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        switch (item.Value)
        {
            case Dictionary<string, string> innerDict:
                foreach (var pair in innerDict)
                {
                    if (pair.Value is null)
                        innerDict.Remove(pair.Key);
                }
                break;
            case null:
                dict.Remove(item.Key);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @aepot - `<string, string>` и `<string, object>` - разные типы. Поэтому нельзя вызвать `RemoveNullValues(innerDict);`

Comment: Возник вопрос, а можно ли модифицировать словарь итерируя его же? Список точно нельзя, а вот про словарь не помню.